# Создание двумерного массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include "stdlib.h" #include "time.h" #include "iostream" #include "conio.h" 
#include "ctime" 
using namespace std;


int fun_rund (int *mass) {

for( int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
    {
        mass[a*b] = (rand()%80)-10;
    }
}
}

int fun_out (int *mass){
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%4d", mass[i*j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
int *A = new int [5*5];
int *B = new int [5*5];
int *C = new int [5*5];


fun_rund(A);
fun_rund(B);
fun_rund(C);

fun_out(A);

return 0;
}
```

создаю, заполняю и вывожу двумерные массивы. Но почему-то числа в первой строке и в первом столбце одинаковые.

28  28  28  28  28

28  -1  28  -6  38

28  28  38  18  43

28  -6  18  12  32

28  38  43  32  36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно делается индексация двумерного массива, замените строчку:

```
 printf("%4d", mass[i*j]);
```

на:

```
 printf("%4d", mass[i*5 + j]);
```

В общем случае, если вы создаёте двумерный массив `mas[m*n]`, то правильное обращение к ячейке с номерами `i, j` будет выглядеть как:

```
mas[i*n + j]
```

Вы сначала отсчитываете нужную строку (сдвигаетесь `i` раз на `n`), затем в найденной строке отсчитываете нужный по счёту элемент.

Comment: при инициализации та же ошибка

Comment: да, уже исправила, спасибо)